# trying to figure out why same output but different results

Tags: python

```
def replace_ending(sentence, old, new):
    # Check if the old string is at the end of the sentence

    # if old in sentence:
    #     i = len(sentence)
    #     N = len(old)
    #     wrong_sentence = sentence[0:i-N] + new
    #     return wrong_sentence

    if old in sentence == True:
        i = len(sentence)
        N = len(old)
        correct_sentence = sentence[0:i-N] + new
        return correct_sentence
    return sentence


print(replace_ending("She sells seashells by the seashore", "seashells", "donuts"))
# # Should display "She sells seashells by the seashore"
```

result top : `She sells seashells by thedonuts`
result bottom : `She sells seashells by the seashore`

I am stuck trying to figure out why both "if statements" yield "True" as output. But, the print results are different. Anyone knows whats causes this?

Comment: Try `if sentence.endswith(old):`

Comment: Ah sorry, i got myself confused. Bill was right, the bottom statement yield false as a result when asked "if old in sentence == True" which is "False". Therefore, it returns just the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Your claim is that all three of these expressions would return the same thing, which is not accurate.

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, Feb 26 2020, 02:56:10)
> ("a" in "aaa") == True
True
> "a" in "aaa" == True
False
> "a" in "aaa"
True
```

Answer (score 0):

*Here is the declaration to what you face*:

```
print("seashells" in "She sells seashells by the seashore == True)
False

print("seashells" in "She sells seashells by the seashore)
True
```

In the first one: '"seashells" in "She sells seashells by the seashore == True"', the `==` operation take action before `in` operation, so if we ask `"She sells seashells by the seashore == True"` the result is `False` then if we continue to ask `"seashells" in False` the result will be `False`

**Therefore:**
`"seashells" in "She sells seashells by the seashore == True"` is not the same as `"seashells" in "She sells seashells by the seashore == True"`

and, the evidence is:

```
print(  ("seashells" in "She sells seashells by the seashore) == True)
True
```

so in your code, you have to use:

```
 if (old in sentence) == True:
```

to get your expected response.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your original question:

> I am stuck trying to figure out why both "if statements" yield "True" as output. But, the print results are different.

The answer is simple, it has to do with the:

### Operators precedence

Doing this:

```py
if old in sentence == True:
```

Is A [Syntactic_sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) of doing this:

```py
if old in sentence and sentence == True:
```

So what's happening is checking separately the 2 statements.

Hence in order to have the correct precedence, (without using the and) you should do this:

```py
if (old in sentence) == True:
```

So it does:

1. Is any character in inside old also in the sentence?.
2. Then Gets the Boolean value and asks Is the result Equal to `True`?

### Documentations and Guides

- [6.17. Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html)

> Note that comparisons, membership tests, and identity tests, all have the same precedence and have a left-to-right chaining feature as described in the Comparisons section.

- [6.10. Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons)

### Final Consideration

This is not what you've asked initially, however comes up naturally that the function you run seem logically wrong (judging by the comments in it, the variables name etc.)

The way you running the if statement, is checking if **any** of the **character** in Old is in the sentence, if yes then add the New word (donuts) to it. So it's obviously true. Would be enough even one character to run that statement true, for instance:

```py
print(replace_ending("She sells seashells by the seashore", "s", "donuts"))
```

Will Give you this anyway, because s is in the sentence:

### Solution

Picture this in a different way, using the [any](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/any), or the [all](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/all) function (I left a print statement so you see what's going on in list l).

**What you are doing so far is the same as this**

```py
def replace_ending(sentence, old, new):

    l = [char in old for char in sentence]
    print(l)
    if any(l):
        i = len(sentence)
        N = len(old)
        correct_sentence = sentence[0:i-N] + new
        return correct_sentence
    return sentence
```

**You want instead (if is this what you want to achieve) use the all function**

```py
def replace_ending(sentance, old, new):


    N = len(old)
    get_last_word = sentance[-(N-1):] # -> Get seashore
    l = [char in old for char in get_last_word] 
    if all(l):
        i = len(sentance)
        correct_sentence = sentance[0:i-N] + new
        return correct_sentence
    return sentance
```

Meaning that **All character should be in the last word of the sentance**.